# How to set a fake time for the java test

Tags: java, spring, testing

I need to test the task on schedule in spring. The task is executed once a day at 4:00 pm. How do I set a fake time in the test so that the spring cron task runs during the test.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting false time in the test you can also set the cron time current time + 5 min delay. hence the scheduler will pick the time and run automatically.